# Regex: Identify second character in a string should be equal to number(9)

Tags: regex

Am looking to identify the second digit that should be matching to digit 9 in a length of 19 numbers string, how to do that using Regex, please let me know.

Ex: 8**9**34567890098765438

dentify the starting 2nd character should match 9 digit only and length of the string should  be greater than 18

I have tried `(?!^.[9])[0-9]{18}`, `[^.[9][0-9]{18}` different ways, but am getting the right one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^(?=.9)\d{19,}$
```

`^(?=.9)` : Second character is `9`.

`\d{19,}$`: 19 or more digits

Comment: Thank you @JGomez and all of you for quick response

Answer (score 1):

You can use a capture group to capture the 9 digit, and match 17 or more chars after it to match at least 19 digits in total:

```
^\d(\9)\d{17,}$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ebuFi8/1)

Or using a positive lookbehind, matching only a 9:

```
(?<=^\d)9(?=\d{17,}$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NFRuSI/1)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
^\d9\d{17}$
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/aWlzIW/1).

With lookahead:

```
^(?=\d9)\d{19}$
```

See [another regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/aWlzIW/2).

When matching a substring of a longer string:

```
\b\d9\d{17}\b
```

(`\b` is a word boundary).